# Python function unexpectedly modifies variable in outer function

Tags: python, function, scope

So I am seeing really strange behavior from my python code and couldn't find any other examples of my problem. From what I've read of python, a function can only access variables that are either global or inside it. However, I've discovered in the following snippet that the two print statements return different results even though the variable 'density' is never returned by the function and isn't declared globally.

```
def findHeight(density):
  print density
  height = integrateHeight(density, cutOff)
  print density
  return height
```

This is a real pain in the a** because it is messing up code later on in the script.

I am using python 2.7.6 and my function definition is as follows:

```
def integrateHeight(data, cutOff):
  # accumulate data values and rescale to fit interval [0,1]
  # Calculate bin widths (first one is a different size from the others)
  data[0,1] = -2*data[0,0]*data[0,1]
  data[1:,1] = (data[2,0] - data[1,0])*data[1:,1]
  # accumulate distribution and divide by the total
  data[:,1] = np.cumsum(data[:,1]) / data[:,1].sum()

  # Assign a default height value
  height = data[0,0]
  # store the first height,fraction pair
  prev = data[0]
  # loop through remaining height,fraction pairs
  for row in data[1:]:
    # check that the cut-off is between two values
    if row[1] > cutOff >= prev[1]:
      # Interpolate between height values
      height = interpolate(cutOff, prev[::-1], row[::-1])
      # exit the loop when the height is found
      break
    # store the current height,fraction value
    prev = row

  return height
```

This particular script is supposed to take a distribution, accumulate it, and find the height corresponding to a certain fraction of the cumulative distribution.

Comment: _"a function can only access variables that are either global or inside it."_ That's something of an oversimplification. For example, a function can also mutate the arguments you pass to it, which seems to be what's happening here. What is the type of the `density` object? Maybe you can make a deep copy of it and pass that instead.

Comment: `data[0,1] = ...` is a much different operation from `data = ...`. The former invokes `data.__setitem__`, the latter changes what the name `data` points to.

Comment: `density` is a `numpy.ndarray` object. I used the `numpy.copy` method when I passed it to integrateHeight and it now works as intended.

Answer (score 3):

The *variable* isn't being modified, the *object you passed to `integrateHeight`* is being modified. This is normal. If you don't want `integrateHeight` to mutate its inputs, write it in such a way that it doesn't mutate its inputs. To do so, you'll probably need to make a copy of it in the function, or find some other way to perform the computation without mutating the object.